# Podcast bandwidth

Tags: web-hosting, bandwidth, podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

**The situation**

Hi folks, I host a medium sized non-commercial audio-only podcast available through the standard ways (website streaming, itunes, stitcher, zune, etc). All these ways of listening are hotlinked back to a simple ftp server running on a VPS. We've recently been asked to leave that VPS because we're averaging 50GB per day of traffic.

**The problem**

I'm looking for a new method of hosting these media files. Transfer speed doesn't matter much, so long as people don't get refused a connection, but overall bandwidth per month does. Also, all the actual site hosting, rss, and other podcasting stuff is already handled and we're not looking to change it. Literally all we need is a new place to store and distribute our media files with hotlinks.

**The solution**

So far, the best solutions I've found are an order of magnitude more expensive that what we have now. All podcast CDNs seem to charge by the GB of transfer, or GB on disk, or both. All the regular webhosting I've found turns me away when they hear that 50GB per day number. I've considered getting several VPSes and trying to balance the load, but that would be an awkward solution, and a badly coded one as well if I had to do it myself. Is there anything I'm missing? I'm willing to look into anything.

Answer (score 1):

Simply upload your podcasts to [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/). Soundcloud doesn't have a bandwidth limit. But it has a limit on the total duration of what you upload. But you can always upgrade.

An advantage of using Soundcloud (besided the bandwidth stuff) is the it provides an easy way for people to embed it (if yuo want it is optional) and it's a great a convenient way for your listeners.

P.S. No I'm not a stakeholder. Just a user who thinks the service is great. I use it to upload my tracks.

Comment: I had already applied to their podcasting program, but my understanding of soundcloud is that it was unusable for large files because of the large amount of processing they have to do on each file. Do they allow hotlinking?

Comment: I checked into it, and in order to use them, we'd need some way of archiving old content or a pro plus account. We broadcast an hour a week.